# HOW: Static company website with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress, content-management-system, static-pages

I have a really stupid question in my mind.

I have used Wordpress to create a website for long time, but I dont want to use it anymore. And now I am looking for little bit different approach. Otherwise, I am quite new in Ruby on Rails. I have read some books and I am not feeling in this matter so confident. So, here is the deal:

My friend asked me to create a simple website for his company. He wants only super simple static website which will contains these pages:

1. Home
2. Products
3. Contact

Each page will contain simple information and there is no need to implement contact forms and other basic functionalities. I also want to deploy this app on Heroku, because he has not a lot of money and we are looking for free hosting. Moreover, I think that the best approach in this matter will be some kind of CMS which will help him to edit the website.

The overview of final solution:

1. Static webpages with simple CMS
2. Using twitter bootstrap for basic layout
3. Deploy on Heroku

I appreciate every contribution in this matter.
Thank you

Comment: "Moreover, I think that the best approach in this matter will be some kind of CMS which will help him to edit the website." --> this complicates things and may not be needed. Much simpler and cheaper to have things in source code and not go the CMS route.

Comment: And what about the Mercury gem? https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury

Answer (score 2):

Everything you have said suggests that you should stick with WordPress.  It's perfectly capable of presenting a non-blog static website (use Pages instead of Posts) and there are some excellent themes available.  WP has, over the years really become a CMS that's also good for blogging.  There are other tools like Drupal that may be appropriate.

I set up a WP site with almost exactly the same goals for some very non-technical people; with a little training they eventually learned how to manage the site, upload images, add content, grant permissions to others, and do a lot of other pretty cool stuff.  I have been using Rails since 2007, but for that case, it was not the right solution.

Rails is a very (very!) sophisticated web development environment used to build complex and scalable dynamic websites.  With power comes a level of complexity several orders of magnitude higher than WordPress.  Even if you use `refinerycms` you still need to do a lot of complicated setup, and need to know a lot of stuff.  Even if you're using Heroku and following a RailsCast like the one for refinerycms, you'll undoubtedly hit some wall where you really need to understand more ... Rails is alluring this way -- seems simple.

If you are using this a reason to learn Rails, and are willing to invest some time, then by all means go for it.  But if you want a simple solution, it's not the way.  Learning Rails is like learning to fly a plane, but harder.

Answer (score 1):

For static pages with rails, you can use [High Voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) gem. You can find the detailed usage of this gem in this [blog post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/11744619917/danger-danger-high-voltage-use-rails-3-1-for-static) . Once you create the pages, then you can easily deploy your app as like normal rails app in the heroku.